# Give priority to two consecutive seizes

Tags: anylogic

I am new in using the seize and resource pool in Anylogic so I am having some difficulties on giving priority to to an specific seize. This is the model that I am building:

[image: Model]

What I am trying to do is that when the seize on position 1 is finished I want to give priority to the seize position1_1. I am using this structure to simulate

I am using this structure to simulate the operation of a car workshop that has a limited workspace (in this case 5). Therefore I want that when I start an activity in a slot all the activities of the same slot are finished and so I don't leave any car waiting half done.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Probably easier if you you dedicated `Seize` and `Release` blocks, i.e. replace the 2 `Service` blocks `position1` and `position1_1` with this:

1. Seize
2. Delay `position1`
3. Delay `position1_1`
4. Release

If needed, you can also put another seize between the 2 Delay blocks.

Also, maybe a `Hold` block before the `SelectOutput5` could help in stopping new cars entering if any of the resources is still busy...